# Ubuntu - Switch to root user from a script file without prompting for password

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am new to Linux. I want to switch to root user from a script file without prompting for password. I am writing this line

echo 'password' | sudo -S su

above runs nicely but does not change user to root user. I have seen that -S does not change user so i tried -i as well but then it prompts for password. Please help

Comment: The approach with `sudo -S` should work for running _sudo_. Try a `echo password|sudo -S id`; it should output the effective uid of root, **provided you have the permission** to do _sudo_. However, the program you are running is `su`,, and this is weird. Why don't you just run a `echo password sudo -S sh`, if you want a root shell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expect script to su to root and perform sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023982/expect-script-to-su-to-root-and-perform-sed)

Comment: Actually i just googled and tried different thing to the task. I will try your suggestion. Thank you